# Trace C# Log Details

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, exception, trace

Is it possible to write a code to trace a log wrote in c#?.
For example:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Error.txt";
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Message :" + ex.Message );
}
```

Now i want to write a code  trace exception message (ex.Message) without open Error.txt.(Note: Code should work for trace any website developed in asp.net+c#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, there's a powerful built-in mechanism for tracing in .NET platform. Refer to [that](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815788) and MSDN documentation. It's implemented through static classes, so you can use it anywhere in your code.
First step is to configure trace listeners via code or `.config` file:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("trace.log");
```

Then, to log a message just call:

```
Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
```

If you just need to check periodically if a certain website is online, you can write something simple like this:

```
Timer t = new Timer(60000);
t.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
        using (HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse) httpReq.GetResponse())
        {
            if (httpRes.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Error.txt",
                    string.Format("Server error: {0} {1}",
                     httpRes.StatusCode, httpRes.StatusDescription));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Error.txt", "Error: "+exc.ToString());
    }
};
t.Start();
```

Or use universal monitoring solution like Zabbix.

Comment: Is it possible to trace without interact client. For example a website (www.tracewebsite.com) wrote in asp.net + c#. Now i want to trace  it log without getting interaction of www.tracewebsite.com . Elaborate with small example.

Comment: What do you mean by interaction? Your website's code executes on server, so all trace messages going to files (or whatever listeners you've configured) on server.

Comment: thanks. i am not going to execute code in server. i have to execute it in my machine. thats the problem. from my system with internet connection i have to trace log details of any other website.

Comment: Well, that's not possible, unless web site is configured to output desired log information. If it's your website, you can enable browser-based [ASP.NET tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx).

Comment: Do you need some kind of web-crawler? May be you can provide an example of information you want to trace?

Comment: In client server system they configured log file. if there is any problem , for solving the issue we have to wait till they give log file to identify issue. so instead i thought to write code to find that log information.clients are there any various places.